# call to malloc appears to modify unrelated data

Tags: c, memory-management

This is my first time posting a question to the forum, by the way.
I'm having problems implementing an algorithm, and I've narrowed it down to the following lines of code:

```
int Jacobi( double** A, double* b, int n, double* x0,
double tol, int maxInt ) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int done = 0;
    int loopCount = 0;

    /*previous x variable*/
    double* xPrev = 0;

    /*update information*/
    double** T = 0;
    double* c = 0;

    /*initialize x previous to a very large value*/
--->xPrev = ( double* )malloc( sizeof( double ) * n );
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
            xPrev[ i ] = 5000.0;
    }
    ...
}
```

By inspection via gdb, I have found that the line with the arrow pointing to it is the one that is causing the trouble. Before that line is executed, x0[ 1 ] = 1. Afterwards, it is somehow changed to x0[ 1 ] = (an extremely small number that I think is the minimum double precision value). I can't figure out why this is happening, or how it is possible. Does anyone have any insight?

Here is the gdb run to prove it:

```
(gdb) break 88
Breakpoint 1 at 0x804881f: file linsys.c, line 88.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/stu1/s11/gaw9451/Courses/AP/hw4/linsys_test

Breakpoint 1, Jacobi (A=0x804b008, b=0x804b048, n=2, x0=0x804b060,
tol=9.9999999999999998e-13, maxInt=8) at linsys.c:88
88              xPrev = ( double* )malloc( sizeof( double ) * n );
(gdb) display x0[ 1 ]
1: x0[ 1 ] = 1
(gdb) next
89              for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
1: x0[ 1 ] = 5.3049894774131808e-313
```

On a possibly related note, I get an error at run time when I free the variable xPrev at the end of the function. I had to comment it out to see any output from my program.

Summary: Does anyone have any idea how malloc can edit data in a **completely different**  variable field?

Thanks in advance,
phoenixheart6

Comment: *"I have found that the line with the arrow pointing to it"* - make sure the arrow doesn't get you in the knee. Anyway, try run your program through a program like *valgrind* to see if you're writing past a buffer in a previous part of the code, which belongs to `xPrev`.

Comment: Would be interesting to see what `xPrev` gets to point to. Since freeing that at the end leads to a crash, it looks like its malloc-data get clobbered.

Comment: Use `valgrind` to help isolate the trouble if it is available to you.  The problem is likely that you are continuing to use memory that was `free()`d.  Or maybe using the pointer to some memory from before it got `realloc()`d to a new address.

Comment: @AusCBloke awesome Skyrim reference lol.
according to gdb, x0 + 1 is 0x804b068 and xPrev is 0x804b070, so 8 bytes beyond x0 + 1.

Comment: @phoenixheart6 But if malloc puts 16 bytes of bookkeeping data before the returned block, a) the malloc data steps on x0[0] and x0[1], b) any write to these two destroys the bookkeeping data, and free(xPrev) crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure you messed up a previous `malloc`, something like allocating less than needed and now `malloc` overwrites what never belonged to you.

Picture the `malloc` memory like this.

```
   +-----------------------------------------------------+
   |xxxxxxxxxx|!!!!!!!|??????????????????????????????????|
   +-----------------------------------------------------+
```

- The `X` region represents what you asked from `malloc`
- The `!` region represents what you wrote **past the legal size**
- The `?` region represents unused memory

Now when you do a second `malloc`, it will feel perfectly entitled to give away "your" `!` part.

Comment: Yes! You were right. I typo-d my allocation of x0:

    x0 = ( double* )malloc( sizeof( double* ) * n );
Thank you very much.

phoenixheart6

Comment: a way to avoid this kind of typo is to use `p = malloc (cnt * sizeof *p);` which always has the right type/size. You could also drop the cast, it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Some trpobles like the one you describe can happen also when you `free` memory twice or erranously. This can happen as well in another function called before, because the mechanism allocating memory is compromized.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: If you caused the use an implicit prototype for `malloc` (e.g. by forgetting to `#include <stdlib.h>` for example), the return value of malloc is essentially scrap, and then attempting to print the contents of that location - even in gdb - can lead to nonsensical results.